# javasscript radio button not working?

Tags: javascript, firefox, radio-button

I am adding attribute for input type radio as checked="checked", in view source it shows but not reflecting in the browser.

edit
`<input type="radio" name="status" value="Yes"  checked="checked"/>

<input type="radio" name="status" value="No" />`

When is check in firebug it shows checked="checked" as shown above, but browser still has no buttons checked.

What might be the cause??

Thanks

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2xS85/

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: @Quentin i am adding the attribute dynamically by javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `checked` attribute sets the *default* checked state, not the current state.

Set the `checked` DOM property to `true` or `false` instead.

```
document.getElementById('for_example').checked = true;
```

Comment: Thanks @Quentin , my problem got resolved, thanks once again for sharing.